# logical 'AND' queries on Array in Flutter Firebase

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, dart

What is the best way to implement AND logic when querying an array in a Firebase call?

I am trying to query a collection of documents that contain an array of characteristics.

The Collection is filled with documents corresponding to people.
Each of the documents contains an array of "characteristics" such as blue eyes, brown eyes, blond hair etc...

I would like to query the collection for documents where the array 'characteristics' contains the entry 'brown hair' AND 'brown eyes'.

```
\\EXAMPLE BAD CODE 
FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('people')
          .where('characteristics', arrayContains: 'brown hair')
          .where('characteristics', arrayContains: 'brown eyes')
          .orderBy('age', descending: true)
          .limit(30)
          .get();
```

Firebase doesn't allow two `where` clause with `arrayContains` however if I use `arrayContainsAny` the list of documents returned may contain people with just brown hair or just brown eyes.

```
\\EXAMPLE WORKING BUT UNDESIRED RESULTS 
FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('people')
          .where('genreTags', arrayContainsAny: ['brown hair','brown eyes'])
          .orderBy('age', descending: true)
          .limit(30)
          .get();
```

What is the best practice for querying an array with two where conditions?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

I see you have worked with traditional relational databases! In Firestore you may have to duplicate data to optimize the reading, or find another way to store data. Maybe instead of a characteristics array you can have a tags sub-document with keys like 'brownHair', 'brownEyes' that are either set to true or left empty.

Untested code:

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('people')
          .where('tags.brownHair', true)
          .where('tags.brownEyes', true)
          .orderBy('age', descending: true)
          .limit(30)
          .get();
```